# Can I get values without key or with wildcard key in Redis?

Tags: redis

Is there any way to get values without key in redis?

My data is as below. Assume that I inserted the three records using `hset`.

```
key     field     value
a-7-1   param1     1
a-7-2   param2     2
a-7-3   param1     3
```

As you can see, there are three keys and I want to extract rows containing `param1`.
So, when I run a redis-cli command, I want to get records as below.
Note that I want to enter single redis command, not for the script containing multiple shell and other commands.

```
key     field     value
a-7-1   param1     1
a-7-3   param1     3
```

I am hard to find any redis-cli that enables those functionality.

I would appreciate it if you could any guidance to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem for [RediSearch](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/). You can create an index over your Hashes and then query it. Like this:

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET a-7-1 param1 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET a-7-2 param2 2
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET a-7-3 param1 3

127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE a-index ON HASH PREFIX 1 a- SCHEMA param1 NUMERIC param2 NUMERIC

127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH a-index "@param1:[-inf +inf]" RETURN 1 param1
1) (integer) 2
2) "a-7-1"
3) 1) "param1"
   2) "1"
4) "a-7-3"
5) 1) "param1"
   2) "3"
```

You'll need a version of Redis with RediSearch installed—I used Redis Stack via Docker—for this sort of stuff.

RediSearch is a big topic—bigger than I can reasonably post here—so you'll need to do some digging on the details. But it's the sort of thing that lets you query Redis and will hopefully be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [hscan](https://redis.io/commands/hscan/) to fetch data with patterns

In your case, you can

```
HSCAN redis-key 0 MATCH param1 100
```